# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here is my code

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Youtube list videos"),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: videoList.map((e) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VideoScreen(
                    name: e['name'],
                    media_url: e['media_url'],
              ))
              ),
              child: Image.network(e['thumb_url']),
            )).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

can anybody tell me where is the mistake here?
[image]

I get this error

[image]

I take url img and videos from youtube
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEHnh.png)

Comment: share your code not image

Answer (score 0):

if You are getting this image form **FireBase** and your image is stored in backend means Imageurl is valid then you have to must enable :

```
              CORS
```

for More Information Please look at this : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#authentication_and_cors